# how can i create the drawer header looks like this from the bottom in flutter

Tags: flutter

[I want to round the bottom of my drawer header like this in the picture in flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irdOG.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irdOG.jpg)

Comment: Please provide some code/attempt. Also show a more zoomed out version of the images. It is extremely hard to see what you want using those images.

Answer (score 0):

use this [clippy_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/clippy_flutter) (Arc type) and put it in the drawer, example:

```
Arc(
                  edge: Edge.BOTTOM,
                  arcType: ArcType.CONVEY,
                  height: 20.0,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/arc_demo'),
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.purpleAccent,
                      width: 100.0,
                      height: 100.0,
                      child: Center(child: Text('Arc')),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```